# Page loading bar in JSF?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

Is there a way to make a progess/loading bar while a JSF page is loading (something like the thing google has when you're loggin into gmail, the thin bar in the top left hand corner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[checkout](http://www.webappers.com/2009/10/02/preload-a-web-page-with-loading-bar-custom-animations/)